# Question regarding the use of "let me" followed by two verbs

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

Well, I have a question regarding these two phrases listed below:

1. let me go make sure
2. let me come see you

I have read some texts using these phrases. I thought the right solution was:

1. let me go **to** make sure
2. let me come  **to** see you

Is it grammatically correct to miss the "to" before the following verb? 
Can I just say: "let me go make sure" and avoid the second version of the phrase?

Comment: You could also simplify the sentences: *let me make sure* and *let me see you*. Do you require the *go* and *come* for some reason?

Comment: Well, As I mentioned, I've read couple of texts with that construction and I just wanted to know, if they're correct grammatically.

Comment: You can say it without **and** but you might not want to write it without **and**.

Answer (score 1):

In "Let me go make sure" the conjunction *and* has been left out. This is a common form (i.e. go do something) in spoken English. It's used to show a result or to tell someone to do something.

> Let me go and make sure (something is right).

In "Let me go to make sure", you have an infinitive of purpose. In other words the speaker is saying

> Let me go so I could make sure (something is right)

I assume you know after *let*, the base form of the verb is used.

Comment: I supposed that it's mainly used in spoken English. I understand the meaning but what if I write it for some official Exam?

Comment: In that case, replace _let_ with _allow_ and probably _make sure_ with _assure_, depending on what the context is. Drop the _go_ thing altogether. You need to rephrase the whole sentence to fit the formal context you aim to use it in.

Answer (score -1):

Even without "let me", in colloquial settings it is possible to combine "go" or "come" with another verb. See: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/295934/139225