# Why is it correct to say "We should go see a movie," but not "We should have gone see a movie"?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Two sentences:

> We should go see a movie. (1)

> *We should have gone see a movie. (2)

The first is correct, the second is incorrect. Why can we omit the word 'to' in the first but not the second?

A simpler example is this: You can say "We go see the movie," but not "We went see the movie."

I am not asking about the meanings of these sentences. I know what they mean. I'm asking why it is possible to omit the word 'to' when 'go' is in the present tense, but not in the past.

Comment: ***Surprise or regret***: 

We sometimes use should to express surprise or regret about something that happened:

-*I’m amazed that he should have done something so stupid.

— I’m sorry that he should be so upset by what I said.* https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/should

Comment: @BenjaminGrange, if your question is just about why the second sentence is incorrect, then I have some suggestions: make it clearer in the question that you know the first is correct and the second is wrong; make it clear in the question that you understand what "should have" means; and change "see" to "seen" because if it were correct, both verbs would be past participles

Comment: Thank you for the advice @gotube. I think you misunderstand my question, because the verbs should not be past participles.

Comment: I found this video which discusses go+bare infinitive https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQoks-C-J0U (Am I allowed to post links to videos here?)

Comment: It's not just *go*: "You should come see me" but not "You should have come see me".

Comment: @PeterShor "You should have come see me" sounds ok to me

Comment: @BenjaminGrange Why don't you think the second verb should be a past participle? Also, to your recent edit, "go" is in the base form, not present tense, because it comes after "should", which always takes base form, and "gone" is a past participle, not the past tense.

Comment: "You should have come see me" sounds like old-movie mobster speak to me. I'm hearing it said with a New York Mafia drawl.

Comment: @gotube Let me get this straight, you think it should be "We should have gone seen the movie"?

Comment: It's because "see a movie" is perceived as a verb. Yes, the whole construct is treated as one verb. However the past tense forms "saw a movie" or "(should have) seen a movie" are perceived as more normal sentences. I've posted this as a comment not an answer, because I do not know the correct linguistic phrase for this behaviour.

Comment: @BenjaminGrange Yep. They're both obviously wrong, but I think "gone seen" is closer. It's immaterial to your question either way since they're not correct.

Comment: You know, as a native speaker, it's not obvious to me whether the past participle of "go see a movie," if it existed, ought to be "gone see a movie," "gone seen a movie," or "go seen a movie." Likewise, clearly the plural present would be (for example) "they go see a movie," but if I wanted to try to say it in the singular present, it's not obvious whether the best choice would be "she goes see a movie," "she goes sees a movie," or "she go sees a movie."

Comment: Technically, "We should go see a movie" is wrong (though it's been too many years since I was in school, so don't remember why), and should formally be "We should go **to** see a movie".  Informally, though, it's fine.  That's why "to" must be in your second sentence.

Comment: "why" questions about English grammar are generally unanswerable.Many rules are just the way we do it.

Comment: Is this question about American English? The first sentence, in British English, is incorrect. It is missing "to", as in, _We should go to see a movie_

Comment: @Oscar Bravo I'm an American

Comment: @BenjaminGrange An American friend once said to Noel Coward that he'd been "horse-back riding". Coward replied, "In England we just say 'riding'; the horse is implied. And, obviously, you sit on its back".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Great question. This construction, sometimes called a **serial verb construction**, mainly works for "go" and "come" (at least in conversational mainstream American English; some other dialects/languages use serial verbs more widely).

It is often used in the imperative, and can be paraphrased by adding "and":

- Go get me a towel. (roughly equal to: Go and get me a towel.)
- Come finish your dinner. (Come and finish your dinner.)

It can also be used to talk about potential future activities (*We should go see a movie* or *Let's go see a movie*). It seems not to work as easily in the past or present (unless "do" is used):

- *I went got you a towel. ("I went and got him a towel" is OK)
- *I am going getting you a towel. (rather: "I am going and getting you a towel")
- *He goes gets her a towel. (rather: "He goes and gets her a towel.")

More examples [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/serial-verbs-definition-1691953).

Comment: Also it can work in the past after "do": "I did go see a movie"; "I didn't go see a movie"

Comment: Thanks I guess I have to stop asking why

Comment: The historical reason probably relates to the meaning conveyed by the construction. Pullum (1990) is one linguistic discussion of the construction that may be of interest: https://kb.osu.edu/bitstream/handle/1811/82130/WPL_39_December_1990_218.pdf

Comment: I would imagine that ‘go’ is linked to the other verb by rection, not agreement, so even when ‘go’ is inflected, the other verb should stay an infinitive. The examples should read ‘I went get you a towel’, ‘I am going get you a towel’, ‘He goes get her a towel’, which are much less *obviously* ungrammatical (if at all).

Comment: I'm willing to stake my life on the claim that no native English speaker has *ever* used the construction "I went get...". You simply cannot omit the 'to' in such a phrase.

Comment: @TomSharpe Maybe not, but the answerer here further transforms it to ‘I went got’, contradicting even the example in the question title. This is a reply to a strawman.

Comment: "should go" and "should have gone" could be analyzed as the present and past (perfect aspect) tense forms of the subjunctive mood, in which case you could explain the usage as something allowed in the imperative and closely related jussive subjunctive moods, but not in the indicative mood displayed in the ungrammatical examples.

Comment: @TomSharpe Actually, it's a common construction in Hawaii Creole English which we just call pidgin here in Hawaii

Comment: While it may be technically correct, each and every example in this answer grates on my nerves. They just sound *wrong*, and somehow low-brow.

Answer (score 21):

The former sounds correct in spoken English, although sounds American to my British ear (i.e., the construction "go see" sounds American). The latter sounds unnatural, although could be rendered "We should have gone **to** see a movie" or "We should have gone **and seen** a movie" and then sound natural.

In formal written English, the former sentence should really have 'to' or 'and' before the verb 'see'. I have no evidence for this, but I believe that the commonality of the construction 'go to [verb]' has led in (primarily American) English to the omission of the word 'to'. My guess is that, since other tenses of the construction (e.g., 'have gone to [verb]' or 'went to [verb]'), while still grammatical, are less common, the omission of 'to' sounds odd.

**The plot thickens:** To my great surprise, I found myself uttering the following spontaneous phrase to my (BrE) wife last night: "Why don't you go brush your teeth?" Later, I asked her what she thought of the phrase "Let's go see a film" (I said 'film' rather than 'movie' so as not to prejudice her), and she also thought it sounded a bit American. But I think it actually might be that we don't 'see films' in the UK; rather, we 'watch films'. So perhaps the construction 'go see' is not the Americanism, but the phrase 'see a (movie/film)'.

Comment: Why are these constructions less common in the past though? I'm not sure 'go see' derives from 'go to see' in the way you suggest. Words don't just disappear for no reason like that.

Comment: My guess is that since the present tense is more commonly used, it was more subject to mutation over time. It's also possible that the present tense, being simpler and more readily understood by people even with a lower skill level in the language, was able to degrade without the supporting 'to' clarifying the composition. Perhaps this is not the case for past and other tenses.

Comment: It sounds American to my BrE ears as well. This sort of construction always reminds me of the song title "Is you is or is you ain't my baby". FWIW "We should have gone *seen* a movie" sounds no more or less "correct" than "We should go see a movie" IMO.

Comment: @BenjaminGrange Words do "just disappear" in spoken English dialects. "We should go *and* see" could naturally mutate into "We should go'nd see," "We should go'n see" and "We should go see".

Comment: "has led" (past tense of 'to lead'), not "has lead" (a dense metal)

Comment: What does the BrE ear think of 'go fly a kite', "go jump in the lake" (or the nsfw epithet derived from the title of the movie: 'Argo')?

Comment: They both sound vaguely American to me, although the former was made famous in the film Mary Poppins, much loved by many Brits. Still, the film was actually an American creation, despite being set in London.

Comment: I’ll take your word that “Go see” sounds informal and American to a Brit today, but it’s been used in formal British English for centuries. For example, the King James Bible has both, “Go, see now this cursed woman, and bury her: for she is a king's daughter.” and “Take now one of the servants with thee, and arise, go seek the asses.”

Comment: Indeed, @TomSharpe: like "our fine four-fendered friend" in _Chitty Chitty Bang Bang_ this was an example of American lyricists writing words which I don't think many English people would say even now, let alone in the time when the films were set.

Comment: It’s even in Chaucer’s *Canterbury Tales*: “And if ye vouche sauf, ye may go see.”

Comment: Well you would expect Americanisms to have roots in Middle or Early Modern English.

Comment: @ColinFine Wow. I've seen that film so many times and never understood what they were saying in that phrase. I had it stored phonetically in my head as nonsense: "our fineful fended friend".

Comment: In my part of the U.S., the past form would usually be contracted: "We should'a have gon't'see a movie"

Comment: Words just disappear in *any* language.

Answer (score 1):

The full phrasing, without leaving out any words, has an infinitive form:

*We should go **to see** a movie.*

Leaving out "to" and just using the verb "see" is OK, but it is chopped phrasing. If you want brevity, leave out both "to" and "go":

*We should see a movie. We should watch a play. We should eat dinner.*

All of these can be filled out, unnecessarily, with "go to do" or "go do" phrasing:

We should go eat dinner. We should go to watch a play.

For something (not) done in the past, you can use the phrase "have gone" and use the full infinitive -- if you are emphasizing the "going" action -- or just use past tense:

*We should have gone to see the play. We should have gone to play tennis.*

*We should have seen the play. We should have played tennis.*

The use of "go" in all its forms in these sentences is really unnecessary, but common. It puts an emphasis on (or at least includes) the movement or travel part of the action of the sentence, rather than just the ultimate action -- see, eat, watch, play.

Comment: I'd agree that the missing word is 'to' rather than 'and', since the former implies going with the intent of seeing, while the latter implies two separate activities.

Answer (score 0):

I have been thinking about this issue since you posted it yesterday, and in particular I've been thinking about *why*, something I don't see other answers addressing (yet). Keep in mind that linguistics is a science, and as such needs to explain what we observe, so flatly saying "this is wrong" doesn't cut the mustard.

That said, natives seem to agree that "we should have gone see a movie" is worse than "we should go see a movie". And the latter does not work in *all* varieties of English. So we need an explanation for why this is.

The best explanation I can think of is this: There are the verbs *come*/*go* which may conjugate, and have participles etc, like many other verbs. Separately, there are also the verbs *come*/*go* which are always infinitive (either bare infinitives or to-infinitives) and which are subject to [serialisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_verb_construction). This second pair of verbs are homonymous with the first pair, but they are not the same words, since they have different syntactic properties.

Others have posted before me, saying that the construction sounds distinctly American. I would agree with that assessment. I could hazard a guess that these verbs are more common in the New World because of influence from African or maybe Asian languages (these areas have languages where serial verbs are much more common), but I'm not sure of this. Wikipedia claims it's survived from Early Modern English, but does not cite a source.

Comment: It likely is from an older version of English.  Counterintuitively, NA English tends to be older than BrE in general, with BrE being more influenced by French, Spanish and German.  Exceptions to the oldness include some new spellings that were intentionally done by Webster to differentiate... but even those trended more towards old forms by dropping French influenced 'ou' in favor of 'o' in words like colo[u]r, valo[u]r, etc... The US 'Midwest' also has a very neutral accent for some of the same reasons.  Everywhere has an accent of course, but it lacks many of the strong tells others have.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_grammatical_differences#Presence_(or_absence)_of_syntactic_elements Covers this particular difference.  All the differences are quite interesting and some of them on the BrE side irritate NA speakers like myself as much as we irritate BrE speakers :P  They cite https://web.archive.org/web/20140219223829/http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/go_1#go_1 for the difference, but say nothing of the origin.

Comment: Ah, you were looking at the serialization article, but they do cite a source, Tallerman, M. (1998). Understanding Syntax. London: Arnold, pp.79–81.  I found the 3rd edition of book here: https://pdfslide.net/reader/f/tallerman-2011-understanding-syntax-3rd-edition, it says: "Finally, if the serial verb construction seems exotic, note that something similar 
was common in sixteenth century English (the time of Shakespeare). An example 
would be Come live with me and be my love; constructions of this type have also 
survived especially in American English, as in Let’s go eat! for example."

Comment: The first of the two quotes can be found published in 1599: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Passionate_Shepherd_to_His_Love  The second doesn't seem specific enough for me to Google-fu the source.

Comment: That settles it. The construction was present this side of the pond as well, and much more common way back when. So why did it "die out" here, and live on there? I don't know the answer exactly. Perhaps under influence of other migrant languages it lived on in NA. And I don't think that any other European languages do this, so maybe the prescriptivists put an end to it here in the UK.

Comment: A poetic quote or two is of course not a strong basis for this claim, we can look at some examples in Google ngrams: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=come+with%2Cgo+see&year_start=1600&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccome%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20see%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccome%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20see%3B%2Cc0  "Come with," was apparently fairly popular and "go see" had a number of spikes as well.

Comment: Maybe, I could be wrong, but I thought the prescriptivist approach was also quite strong in NA, particularly in the Midwest, but they may have been prescribing quite different things.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to the much-debated question:
Does society influence language or language influence society?

I think what you are witnessing at the former sentence is "society influencing language" as native English speakers tend to use it in their daily conversations, more of an informal usage. So it sounds grammatically wrong to a new learner, maybe sounded wrong to a native speaker years ago.

On the other hand, the latter also sounds grammatically wrong to a new learner. And this time, it sounds strange or even wrong to say it in daily conversations. As a result, it is not approved.

In conclusion, society altered present but not the past or future :)

Answer (score -1):

#### Both are equally incorrect

The former should be "go ***to*** see", or slightly less formally "go ***and*** see". Colloquial American English often omits both. You won't often hear this in Britain though, except as influenced by American phrasing picked up from films/TV/internet, but Brits will understand it well enough.

And with that in mind, Brits will understand the latter equally well too.

Neither is truly correct English grammar though, in either American or standard English.

Comment: What's your basis for saying it's incorrect when native speakers of all kinds will understand it without issue, and most will use it too?

Comment: I completely agree with this answer. As an Indian I am accustomed to British English - and though the OP's examples would sound all right (albeit informal) in spoken word, I would probably flinch a bit if I see them in a formal context like in a news report. It's somewhat similar to 'gonna' or 'wanna' - one doesn't use them in something that needs to be precise in grammar.

Comment: @curiousdannii That's the difference between grammatically correct according to the rules; colloquially used as part of a local dialect; or "with a bit of effort we understand what you were trying to say". This falls between the second (for Americans) and the third (for everyone else). "Correct" would mean it follows the rules of English grammar (at least for some version of English), but it doesn't.

Comment: @Graham do you have the formalised list of rules of AmE grammar to check that?

Comment: This is a massively unhelpful answer because it conflates two different things. _Have gone see_ is ungrammatical in AFAIK all varieties of English: that is to say, no native speaker would say it, and if they heard it they would think it an error or said by a non-native speaker. _Go see_ is fully grammatical for some speakers of English (not all), but is "incorrect" according to many people's social judgment. You're free to regard them both as "incorrect", but "equally"? Absolutely not. The incorrectness is different in kind, not in degree.